# как правильно сохранять данные в разные таблицы с одной формы? Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
к примеру есть таблица Roles
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
     /**
   * разрешения, принадлежащие роли.
   */
  public function permissions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
  }
}

соответственно есть таблица pivot permission_role:
permission_id   bigint unsigned 
role_id bigint unsigned 

нужно отдельно сохранять сразу  часть данных 
class RoleController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'display_name' => 'required|string|max:20',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:20',
            
        ]);

        $role = new Role();
            $role->display_name = $request->input('display_name');
            $role->name = $request->input('name');
            $role->save();

      и потом сохранять Permission ? и в таблицу pivot permission_role?

    }
}
```

спасибо!

Comment: У вас же ORM. В разные таблицы данные положит сам [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

Comment: как именно в данном примере?

Comment: Если пермишны уже заведены в системе и вы просто назначаете их роли, то, например, так:
`$role->permissions()->sync($permissionIds);`